# DateDiff for [datetime2](7) in hh:mm;ss format

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Duration     (startDate datetime2, endDate datetime2);

INSERT INTO dbo.Duration (startDate, endDate)  VALUES ('2007-05-06 16:42:09', '2007-05-07 11:10:08');  
INSERT INTO dbo.Duration (startDate, endDate)  VALUES ('2007-05-07 08:30:09', '2007-05-07 12:12:43');  
INSERT INTO dbo.Duration (startDate, endDate)  VALUES ('2007-05-07 11:35:09', '2007-05-07 17:13:39');
```

Below is the query to be modified as per the expected result

```
SELECT   DATEDIFF(day, startDate, endDate) AS Duration      FROM dbo.Duration;
```

Expected Result:

```
19:32:01
04:18:34
06:22:29
```

Comment: What do you want to see if difference is more than 24 or 100 hours?

Comment: If you have a date difference of more than 24 hours would you expect this to show as `25:32:12` or `1d 01:32:12`? As an aside, duration *should* be a number not a time, this specific subject is covered in the article [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) (in the section "Using TIME to store duration")

Comment: HOw do you even get to those values? For example, between the dates `2007-05-06 16:42:09` and `2007-05-07 11:10:08` the time difference is 18  hours, 27 minutes, 59 seconds. How do you get `19:32:01`???

Comment: @Lamu the value i have given for showing the format only. its not for calcaution.

Comment: Then show us the expected results for your data, not some sample data and then some random data that has nothing to do with your question!

Comment: @ExLo The date can be taken as more than hours say.. more than 24 will be termed as 27:03:44

Comment: @Lamu 
Expected Result:

18:27:59
03:42:34
05:38:30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following query.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATEADD(MS, DATEDIFF(MS,startDate, endDate), 0), 108) AS TimeDiff from Duration
```

Comment: what is the datatype i have to create to save the result into an table

Comment: You can use TIME or else use VARCHAR.

Comment: CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATEADD(MS, DATEDIFF(MS,Stat_EndTime, Stat_StartTime), 0), 108) AS [VisitTime], 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATEADD(MS, DATEDIFF(MS,Load_EndTime, Load_StartTime), 0), 108) AS [LoadTime]
above is fine.
 When i did a join as below for the complete difference time, i am getting error 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATEADD(MS, DATEDIFF(MS,Stationary_EndTime, Stationary_StartTime), 0), 108) - CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATEADD(MS, DATEDIFF(MS,LoadingEndTime, LoadingStartTime), 0), 108) AS [Actual Contact Time], 
--The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the subtract operator. –

Comment: You can't use subtract operator in the above query. Can you put the clear data and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
with cte as
(
select    DATEDIFF(second, startDate, endDate) AS Duration      FROM dbo.Duration
) select Duration AS 'seconds',
   CONVERT(varchar(20), DATEADD(second, Duration, 0), 108) AS 'hh:mm:ss' from cte
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=421bcf5ad9bc1a4eeccaa8c5dac31380)

```
seconds hh:mm:ss
66479   18:27:59
13354   03:42:34
20310   05:38:30
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: @GarethD thanks edited

Comment: what is the datatype i have to create to save the result into an table